# delphi. send command to open POS drawer

Tags: delphi, printing, point-of-sale

I bought the Xprinter model XP-58H, which comes with a drawer. I have checked this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31638043/how-to-send-control-commands-to-pos-printer-from-delphi) but it uses COM port, while mine is USB/Bluetooth. Is there any way I could send a command to open the drawer? I'm using Delphi 10.2.

i use code but it just print.

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
  lst: TextFile;
begin
  AssignPrn(lst);
  Rewrite(lst);
  try
    Write(lst, #27#112#0#150#250);

  finally
    CloseFile(lst);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: A "COM port" does not contradict the use of the device via a USB/Bluetooth interface.

Comment: What does the documentation say on how to send data to the printer?